# Devise CanCanCan Rolify - Not blocking unauthorised requests - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancancan, rolify

I have completed the [Devise CanCanCan rolify Tutorial](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Devise---CanCanCan---rolify-Tutorial). I have ended up with the below `Ability` class:

```
can :manage, Group, id: user.groups.pluck(:id)
```

How should I be setting up my controllers? I saw in the CanCanCan docs [here](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Controller-Authorization-Example) that the `load_and_authorize_resource` controller method is meant to do the magic for you.

I am also using a `:slug` as the identifier for a record with `load_resource find_by: :slug, id_param: :slug`.

I have tried this, but none of the unauthorized requests were being blocked anymore:

```
class GroupsController < ApplicationController
  load_resource find_by: :slug, id_param: :slug
  authorize_resource

  ...
end
```

Is this the correct way to go about it?

Thanks

Comment: show me your ability class

Comment: @uzaif Added to question.

Comment: did you add friendly id support in `cancancan`?

Comment: I am not using friendly_id, It's just another field in the database which gets a randomized slug generated on record creation to look something like `48oA8fQu`.

Comment: its alias field in db right?

Comment: What do you mean "alias field"?

Comment: try this `can :manage, Group, id: user_id`

Comment: I don't see that wrking... If this is what you are trying to say, I get the same result: `can :manage, Group, user_id: user.id`..

I was able to prove the `Ability` class is set up correctly by printing on the view: `<p>Allowed to be here? <%= can?(:edit, @organization) %></p>`. It seems to be something wrong with the `authorize_resource` call in the controller...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145271/discussion-between-uzaif-and-slehmann36).

Comment: override `set_(resource)` method in your controller